# What is the frequency associated to the orbitals within an atom?

Tags: electrons, atoms, frequency, vibrations

I was told that there's a vibrational frequency associated to the orbitals within an atoms, but it is a frequency related not to a classical vibration. What Hz frequencies would these be?

Comment: Which atom? And I don't think classical will come into it but hope you get an answer.

Comment: Acid Jazz -- I just edited the description. I meant to say 'atoms', plural. All atoms.

Comment: Atoms in a molecule, which I guess you mean, can vibrate at different frequencies, like they are attached with springs, also they can rotate and maybe because they can only do these things at certain vibration frequencies, not just any random frequency, (as you can in classical), maybe that's what they meant. But different molecules have different frequencies of vibration and rotation.  so it depends on which molecule you are dealing with. Sorry if you know this already.

Comment: Acid Jazz -- They specifically meant the electrons within any type of atom. Can't get any type of reply. But they said a non classical frequency.

Comment: Acid Jazz -- By the way, you mentioned atoms in a molecule being able to vibrate at specific frequencies. What Hz frequencies?

Comment: In general terms, the electrons in an atom have certain energy levels, so if an electron has one unit of energy, the next one **must** have 2, 3, 4.... times that amount, it can't have 1.5 or 2.23 times the bottom level.So it's  different than classical,  only electrons with certain energies ( or vibration, same idea) will fit into the atom.

Comment: Acid Jazz -- I'm aware of the energy levels within electrons of atoms. But you had mentioned the atoms in molecules vibrating at different frequencies. What would the frequencies of the atoms be in Hz (the range)?

Comment: http://www.chemtube3d.com/vibrationsCO2.htm   have a look at that link, they show different molecules and they use wavelength not frequency but it's the same idea in general

Comment: Atoms don't vibrate, at all. If you take the expectation value of a wave function in an energy Eigenstate, it's perfectly stationary. One has to couple an atom to a radiation field, which makes excited states metastable, ONLY then is there a time dependent term which corresponds to the decay of those states.

Comment: CuriousOne -- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_vibrations -- this is how I've understood it

Comment: Acid Jazz -- Very neat presentation. Thanks for that link.